# Returning Gibberish character in browser via Ajax Call

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, response

I have Ajax call which return JSON in response, Backend is written in servlet, and I have set `content-type` and `character-set` as well

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

But in Ajax response , I see gibberish character like Bullet turns into � .

Any idea why this is happening?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is a replacement character:

It is used to indicate problems when a system is unable to render a stream of data to a correct symbol. It is usually seen when the data is invalid and does not match any character

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)#Replacement_character

Comment: Is there anyway to fix this up?

Comment: Can you share the characters that are being replaced?

Comment: 3. PRINCIPAL ACCOUNTABILITIES<br>(Accountabilities associated with the job)
• Shaping the Product Design solution and process on a project, defining the deliverables, and the team’s time to execute those deliverables
• Identify opportunities for innovation and collaborate across teams and functions to invent something new
• Organize and lead workshop experiences and facilitate colleagues through design led exercises

**Above bullet converts into � character.**

Comment: is this returning these values from the backend call? or is it mis-rendered by the browser?

Comment: It is mis-rendered by browser.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use bullet directly. Use the equivalent hexcode or html code and it should work.

The browser/DOM doesn't identify some characters. Check the link below:

https://www.toptal.com/designers/htmlarrows/punctuation/bullet/

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions to this problem can be :

1. Setting the response with appropriate charset in the backend layer.
2. Setting appropriate charset on view/frontend layer.
3. Setting appropriate charset on the database layer.

In my case, it was utf8 [or you can use utf8mb4 based on your needs].